# Calculate the following integral

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-integration

$$\int_{[0,1]^n} \max(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \, dx_1\cdots dx_n$$

My work:

I know that because all $x_k$ are symmetrical I can assume that $1\geq x_1 \geq \cdots \geq x_n\geq 0$ and multiply the answer by $n!$ so we get that $\max(x_1\ldots,x_n)=x_1$ and the integral that we want to calculate is
$n!\int_0^1 x_1 \, dx_1 \int_0^{x_1}dx_2\cdots\int_0^{x_{n-1}} \, dx_n$ and now it should be easier but I'm stuck..

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try the case $n=2$ first.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/292521/321264,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/745067/321264

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can see by induction that:

$$\int_0^1 x_1 dx_1 \int_0^{x_2 } dx_2 \cdots = \int_0^1 x_1 \frac{x_{n - (n-1)}^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} dx_1 =\frac{1}{(n+1) \times (n-1)!}$$

Therefore, the original integral is:

$$n! \times \frac1{(n+1) \times (n-1)!} = \frac{n}{n+1}$$

Answer (score 13):

**This is an alternative approach.**

Let $X_i$ ($i=1,\cdots , n$) be independent uniform random variable in $[0,1]$.

What is the PDF of $M=\max (X_1, \cdots, X_n)$?

Then what is $\mathbf{E}[M]$?

Comment: Ah,  a probabilistic approach. Nice.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: knowing the properties of Beta distributions make this rather easy

Answer (score 7):

Note that $\max(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=\max(x_1,\max(x_2,\dots,x_n))$.  In addition, note that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\max(x,y)\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^y y\,dx+\int_y^1 x\,dx\right)\,dy\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac12+\frac12 y^2\right)\,dy
\end{align}$$

Now, we can write

$$\begin{align} \int_0^1  \max(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\,dx_1&=\int_0^1  \max(x_1,\max(x_2,\dots,x_n))\,dx_1\\\\
&=\int_0^{\max(x_2,\dots,x_n)}\max(x_2,\dots,x_n)\,dx_1+\int_{\max(x_2,\dots,x_n)}^1x_1\,dx_1\\\\
&=\frac12 +\frac12\left(\max(x_2,\dots,x_n)\right)^2
\end{align}$$

Then, observe that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{k}\int_0^1 \left(\max(x_k,\dots ,x_n)\right)^{k}\,dx_k&=\int_0^{\max(x_{k+1},\dots ,x_n)}\left(\max(x_{k+1},\dots ,x_n)\right)^k\,dx_k+\int_{\max(x_{k+1},\dots ,x_n)}^1 x_k^k\,dx_k\\\\
&=\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\left(\max(x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)\right)^{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{k(k+1)}+\frac{1}{k+1}\left(\max(x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)\right)^{k+1}
\end{align}$$

Proceeding inductively, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\cdots \int_0^1 \max(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\,dx_1\cdots dx_n&=\frac1{(2)(1)}+\frac{1}{(3)(2)}+\frac{1}{(4)(3)}+\cdots +\frac{1}{(n+1)(n)}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{n}{n+1}
\end{align}$$

Comment: +1. It's an elegant proof. Given the quite simple and unexpected result, we always think it must be some simple or, lets say, 'direct procedure'. This 'theorem' doesn't seem to be true, anyway.

Comment: @felixmarin Thank you!  And very much appreciated as always.  -Mark

Answer (score 7):

This is pretty straightforward using probabilistic methods: What you're looking for is

$$E[\max_{1 \le i \le n} X_i] = \int_{[0,1]^n} \max x_i \ \ dx_1\dots dx_n$$

where $X_i$ are iid uniformly distribuited on $[0,1]$.

Now call $Y = \max_i X_i$; its distirbution function is given by

$$F_Y(x) = P(\max X_i \le x) = \prod_i P(X_i \le x) = x^n \ \ \ \text{  $x \in [0,1]$}$$

Hence $Y$ is absolutely continuos and its density is given by 
$$f_Y(x) = nx^{n-1}1_{[0,1]}(x)$$

Hence we find that

$$E[\max X_i] = E[Y] = \int_\mathbb R xf_Y(x) dx = \int_0^1 nx^n dx = \frac n{n+1}$$