# Expectation of the maximum of two exponential random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation, exponential-distribution

Let $Z:=\text{max}(X,Y)$ where $X,Y$ are independent random variables having exponential distribution with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively.

My question is:

> What is the expectation of $Z$,  i.e. what is $\mathbb{E}(Z)$?

Comment: Do you mean that $X\sim \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for $\lambda>0$? Also, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/197304/259085) may be useful.

Comment: You (most probably) forgot to mention that $X,Y$ are independent.

Comment: @Lovsovs, yes I did intend that. And that was very useful - thanks!

Comment: @drhab Oops, yes I did forget to mention that.

Comment: It is by far the most frequent lack by questions about probability.

Comment: @UncleIroh Great! You can edit your question and correct your question by clicking the small "edit"-button under your answer.

Comment: @Lovsovs Actually, I am unsure as to the difference between $X\sim \lambda e^{-\lambda x} $ for $\lambda>0 $ and $X\sim e^{\lambda} $

Comment: @UncleIroh Well, they are completely different expressions. If $\lambda>0$ for both, $e^\lambda$ isn't even a valid PDF.

Comment: @Lovsovs Ah yes, in my original posting, I had intended to mean that $X \sim exp(\lambda) $ is equivalent to $X$ is a random variable with an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @UncleIroh No problem! That (especially wit the captital E in Exp, which I think you used) is actually also pretty standard notation, I don't know why I misinterpreted it, so I'm the one that should be apologizing. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Make use of: $$\mathbb EZ=\int_0^{\infty}P(Z>z)dz$$

and of course:$$P(Z>z)=P(X>z)+P(Y>z)-P(X>z\wedge Y>z)$$

By independence of $X,Y$ this results in:$$P(Z>z)=P(X>z)+P(Y>z)-P(X>z)P(Y>z)$$

Comment: $$P(Z>z)=P(X>z)+P(Y>z)-P(X>z \wedge Y>z) $$
$$P(Z>z)=P(X>z)+P(Y>z)-P(X>z)P(Y>z) $$
$$P(Z>z)=e^{-\lambda z}+e^{-\mu z}-e^{-(\lambda+\mu) z} $$
$$\mathbb{E}(Z)=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda z}+e^{-\mu z}-e^{-(\lambda+\mu) z} dz = \cfrac{1}{\lambda}+\cfrac{1}{\mu}-\cfrac{1}{\lambda+\mu} $$

Comment: Well, that makes things easy, doesn't it? Excellent!

Comment: Another way is exploiting $\max(X,Y)=X+Y-\min(X,Y)$. Then you can take advantage of the fact that a minimimum of expontially distributed variables is also expontially distributed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer meets your needs then you could accept it.